# What is the wrong with my sql query?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I want to make a code but it is showing me a wrong text

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'DVR' to data type int.

Where is the problem I don't know? There is no data in my table so previous voucher value is zero. Please help..

```
select 
   'DVR'+ DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) + 
          RIGHT('00000' + convert(varchar, (ISNULL(MAX(right(voucher, 5)), 0) + 1)), 5) as vno 
from 
   tblledger 
where 
   left(isnull(voucher, 0), 3) = 'DVR'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DATEPART` returns integer, while 'DVR' is a string. Obviously, your SQL engine tries to cast 'DVR' to integer and fails. Try converting the result of `DATEPART` to string (e.g. varchar) using `CAST`.

Answer (score 0):

Is voucher a numeric type? If so, then the error message makes sense as you are trying to compare to 'DVR' which is VARCHAR.

Comment: this is a comment not an answer

Comment: No, voucher is VARCHAR type. and it should be like DVR1500001